# amazon lambda expose internal server error

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm writing an aws lambda in python in an organisation where I'm not allowed to touch the aws build console or look at logs - so it's basically check in and retry calling it heaps of times until it seems that it's deployed.   50% of the time I just get "internal server error" and have to randomly try stuff until its resolved.  I have a top level error handler inside my function handler - but there seem to be many other things that cause errors - such as adding several functions to the python code.

the question

I *can* talk to the people who access the lambda settings - is there a way of configuring the lambda or the api gateway so that if something gets wrong, details of what went wrong are actually returned to the caller (ie me?)

The gateway is setup to call it in lambda proxy mode, and it's returning text/html most of the time.

Comment: Can you use your own AWS account for development purposes?

Comment: I do that - but it works perfectly in my account - so it's something to do with the settings on the other lambda